# Learn model/manufacturer relationship

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on the Used Cars Dataset found in Kaggle. I will narrow the table to summarize the situation.

[Dataframe:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWrbA.png)

Here is the question;
-How can I teach that model belongs to that manufacturer?

Ex:
I know 'New Sierra 1500' produce by GMC. How can I let the machine know this?

Goal:
I want to fill missing values on dataframe. I will fill the missing values of manufacturer according to the model (if the model is na, the model is according to the manufacturer).

adding : I dont know if there is a ready-made machine learning model for this.

Comment: Your statement, "if the model is na, the model is according to the manufacturer", would only be true if the manufacturer only made one model, right?

Comment: Actually, no. Example: New Sierra 2500hd also produced by GMC.

Comment: Well, if GMC has a minimum of two models, how can you infer which of them it is, based solely on brand?

Comment: I didnt understand what you asked

Comment: You stated, "if the model is na, the model is according to the manufacturer", and my point is that if the model is unknown, and the manufacturer makes different models, how will you infer which model it should be? It could be both 'New Sierra 1500' or 'New Sierra 2500hd'?

Comment: in raw dataset i have more information. for example; drive(4wd,rwd,fwd), transmission, size, type etc. i'll try to predict the model according to these properties. It will not be completely correct, but I want to reach the closest result.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I missunderstood what you were trying to accomplish.